# Cast/Convert BigInt to Varchar in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How might I Cast/Convert BigInt to Varchar in MySQL?

Comment: I have tried Cast( bigIng_field, varchar) and Cast( bigIng_field, varchar( some_length ), but they doesn't work!

Answer (score 21):

```
mysql> select  Cast( 12345678901234567890 as char) ;
+-------------------------------------+
| Cast( 12345678901234567890 as char) |
+-------------------------------------+
| 12345678901234567890                | 
+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This improves my answer a lot, thanks for your effort

Answer (score 4):

I think you can't cast to `varchar`, try `char` instead.
Or are you trying to modify the type of an existing field of a table? Then you have to do for example:

`ALTER TABLE MODIFY COLUMN mycolumn varchar(50);`