# Timestamp to datetime in SQL (PHPmyAdmin)

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, phpmyadmin, timestamp

I have a problem.

I have a table with BigInt dates. That BigInt are for example **20160614041115** (Date: 2016/06/14 04:11:15)

In other table I have DateTime dates.

I need to compare that dates...

I try **from_unixtime(mytimestamp)** but mytimestamp isn't a Unix Timestamp. Also try **STR_TO_DATE(mytimestamp,'%Y%m%d%h%i%s')**, and also **STR_TO_DATE(CAST (mytimestamp AS VARCHAR),'%Y%m%d%h%i%s')**...

Nothing work... Any ideas?? :(

Thanks in advance

Comment: This? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367603/mysql-convert-int-to-datetime

Comment: One way is to cast the bigint to `char` (not varchar) then use that in `str_to_date`. maybe interesting? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259350/cast-convert-bigint-to-varchar-in-mysql. Also: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date It doesn't seem that efficient to me. Still it should work.

Comment: Thanks @RyanVincent !!!! :) Your solution works perfectly.

Comment: And @user3741598, like I said before, my timestamp is NOT unix timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved it is [Ryan Vincent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3184785/ryan-vincent)'s solutions. Like I said before, my timestamp is not a Unix Timestamp so I could'n use from_unixtime() function.

So, for anyone who need the answer, I finally use **STR_TO_DATE + CAST**...

**STR_TO_DATE(CAST(mytimestamp AS CHAR), '%Y%m%d%h%i%s')**

And go from this: **20160613005300**

To this: **2016-06-13 00:53:00**

Thanks for your answers!!!